# Should off-topic questions be answered?

Tags: discussion

Well the title says it.  Should I answer a question that is technically (or blatantly) off-topic if I know the answer?  Example: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697604/why-there-is-a-need-in-different-lnixues) got a downvote as well as multiple flags from me.  If I can just answer the question so that the user will be satisfied and go away, should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer: no

- you cast a close vote against an appropriate category.
- you can also then downvote.

Refer [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)

If the question is likely to be migrated to another site, answer it.

Comment: Users who answer off topic questions will *not* be reprimanded. By the way.

Comment: ^ THAT is what I was hoping to hear.  Thanks Stefano.

Comment: @Daniel They won't, but then such people will be enabling useless users who can't be bothered about the quality of the site.